# Auto force close?

Tags: android

I having abit of problem here as when i saw somewhere with calculator codes and use it somehow the app always force close when i started keying in numbers. help?

```
public void onClickListener8(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonClear);
    }
    eight=(String)button8.getText();
    sum=sum+eight;
    editText.setText(sum);
}


04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  ... 11 more
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException:     Requires VIBRATE permission
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.IVibratorService$Stub$Proxy.vibrate(IVibratorService.java:106)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:52)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at     com.mypackage.Calculator.onClickListener8(Calculator.java:232)
04-17 15:38:23.110: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: get a copy of your 'adb logcat' output and post it here, your app has a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app has the Vibrate permission. The following line should be there in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, look at the log, it clearly says:
Requires VIBRATE permission

Answer (score -3):

I think you must be using an emulator.  Just comment out the vibrate; somehow that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: but how come it will cause this kinda of problem i dun have this issue when running on my phone

Comment: i also not very sure abt this but i know if u r using the original settings somehow the vibrate will cause u error as also shown on ur logcat

Comment: commenting off may not be an option